# Python: more concise logic/syntax on empty strings

Tags: python, django, logic, string

I'm looking for a more concise way to write the below in Python.

Given an input, check if either of two variables are in the input:

```
if (input is not None and (
    (var_a == '' or (var_a != '' and var_a not in input))
    or (var_b == '' or (var_b != '' and var_b not in input))
)):
    # Do something...
    pass
```

Because `'' in 'any string'` evaluates to `True` I can't simply test for `var_a not in input`, hence the added complexity above of also checking if the variables are empty string.

Hopefully I'm just overlooking a simpler way of expressing this.

Thanks.

P.S. my variables aren't really named `input`, `var_a` and `var_b`, don't worry.

Comment: simply `var_a` can replace `var_a != '' "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if input is not None and (
   not var_a or var_a not in input or  # Should this be 'or' or 'and'? 'or' looks unusual here
   not var_b or var_b not in input):
    pass
```

You can skip checks for `var_a != ''` because after `var_a == '' or` they will always be `True`. Check `var_a == ''` is equivalent to `not var_a` if `var_a` can't be `None` (and I guess it can't be, because you don't check for it)

**Edit**:

Now that I think of it you can also factor `not` out of the second bracket:

```
if input is not None and not(
   var_a and var_a in input and
   var_b and var_b in input):
    pass
```

... or out of the whole expression:

```
if not (input is None or 
        var_a and var_a in input and
        var_b and var_b in input):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition if var_a or var_b are not falsey i.e empty they must be True so you only need a single check, not a check for both conditions:

I would nest an any inside an `if inp is not None`:

```
if inp is not None:
    if any((not var_a, var_a not in inp, not var_b, var_b not in inp)):
        # do whatever

In [26]: var_a = ""

In [27]: var_b = ""

In [28]: inp = "foo"

In [29]: (not var_a, var_a not in inp, not var_a, var_a not in inp)
Out[29]: (True, False, True, False)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list = [var_a, var_b, input]
if '' in list == FALSE:
        if var_a is in input or var_b is in input:
           # do something
else:
   #do something
```

Comment: That might do what you need.